Bond option on price vs bond option on yield
Let the bond option paying $(K_P-P_T)^{+}$ at maturity $T$, where $K_P$ is the strike on the price of the bond and $P_T$ the price of the bond at maturity of the option. Suppose also that quoted premiums for this option today for different values of the strike are given.
I would like to price an option on the yield instead of the price. This option pays $(K_y - y_T)^{+}$, where $K_y$ is the strike in terms of yield and $y_T$ is the yield of the bond at the maturity of the option.
I would like to assume that yield is normal and use Bachelier to price this option. My question is, how does one translate the resulting premium of an option on the price of the bond into the premium of an option on the yield

I believe it should be possible to use a Taylor polynomial here:
Let's write $f(B_T) = y(K)-y(B_T)$, where $y$ denotes the (decreasing) function converting bond prices to yields.
Then $f(B_T) = f(K) + f'(K)\cdot(B_T-K)+\int_K^{B_T} f''(t)\cdot(B_T-t) dt$ and $f(B_T) = f'(K)\cdot(B_T-K)^{+}+\int_K^\infty f''(x)\cdot(B_T-x)^{+}dx$ for $B_T>K$ (note that $f(K)=0$).
As such the pay-off $[y(K)−y(B_T)]^{+}$can be written as $-y'(K)\cdot[B_T-K]^{+}-\int_K^\infty y''(x)\cdot(B_T-x)^{+}dx$.

The previous answer is basically correct, but needs to be applied the other way round
$K_P-P_T$ can be written in terms of yields as $P(Y_K)-P(Y_T) \sim (Y_K - Y_T) \cdot P'_y$ where $P'_y$ is negative.
So $(K_P-P_T)^+ = (Y_T - Y_K)^+ \cdot (-P'_y)$
$P'_y$ is traditionally called DV01 or BPV which is quoted without the minus sign, so be careful. You need a positive value as a factor.
The question at which point to compute the derivative is left unanswered and ultimately absorbed into the volatility implied from market prices. But its impact will be anyway limited.
